# How to access user's phone number in Twilio SMS Bot application with Python and Flask?

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I'm currently creating an SMS Bot with Twilio, Python, and Flask. I want to store user's input in a mongodb database, and I planned to sort through the db using the user's phone number. Anyone know how I can get this phone number?
Example:

Jeff (Number: +123456789) sends a text to Bot(Number: +1987654321). How can the Bot figure out what Jeff's number is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your Flask app, you can get the inbound number with this Python code:

```
num = request.values.get('From')
print(num)
```

Let me know if this helps :D